# Do kidney beans or pinto beans grow stolons/runners?

Tags: plant-care

I'm planning on growing pinto and kidney beans in a garden, and was wondering if they made stolons/runners like some plants, ex: mint. I don't want them to take over my garden and kill everything else. If they do produce stolons/runners, I'm planning on buying a barrier.

Comment: I have planted them because nobody answered, I will update question in a few months